# InfluxDB : Count number of records in whole database

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to count the numbers of points that have been stored in my InfluxDB Database... Is this the way to do it ?

```
SELECT count("pointReq") FROM "_internal"."monitor"."write"
```

(I have several measurements in this database.)

**Edit :** Maybe it is this query instead :

```
SELECT last("pointReq") FROM "_internal"."monitor"."write"
```

Comment: No, this only gives you the writes, which is different to whether they still exist (retention policies or explicit queries may have removed them)

Comment: Is there any reliable way to know it ?

Comment: I've done it in the past, but can't remember how.